# Dexguard crashing after library added with native code

Tags: android, gradle, dexguard

After adding a library to project that contains native code (embedded as `.so`), my app build started to crash when running the `dexguard<Flavor><BuildType>` task.
The error says:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't read [/home/user/project/app/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs/flavor/buildType/folders/2000/1f/main(;;;;;;lib/*/*.so,lib/*/gdb*)] (Can't write resource [lib/x86/filecointainedonlibrary.so] (New string section exceeds the length of the original: 243 > 242))
```

Answer (score 1):

That might happen when DexGuard obfuscates your native methods.

The latest version 7.1.29 should fix this issue, please give it a try.

Edit: The troubleshooting section of the DexGuard manual describes work-arounds when this happens. They basically keep names of native methods.